# Django fandjango migration 4.2

Tags: python, django, facebook, fandjango

After migration fandjango to version 4.2., I've got an error when I access my facebook application:

Exception Value: [u'Enter valid JSON']

Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jsonfield/fields.py in pre_init, line 77

Trace:

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jsonfield/subclassing.py in **set**
            obj.**dict**[self.field.name] = self.field.pre_init(value, obj)
    ...

jsonfield.subclassing.Creator object at 0x2a5c750

obj
User: My User

value u''

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jsonfield/fields.py in pre_init
                            raise ValidationError(_("Enter valid JSON"))
    ...

▼ Local vars
Variable    Value
self
jsonfield.fields.JSONField: extra_data

obj
User: My User

value   u''

I have upgraded fandjagno using pip install -upgrade fandjango, python manage.py migrate fandjango.

There were another problems:

-No module named jsonfield, so I installed it using pip

-No module named dateutil.tz, so I installed it as well.

-Also it asked for property DJANGO_SITE_URL, which was not defined in the settings object. I putted also it in the settings file. However I didn't find any documentation about this property.

So now I am trying to figure out what else is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I get it. The problem was with mysql database. The new version added a json field extradata. MySql interpreted it as text field with NULL value. So the problem was that fandjango wanted empty json, not NULL. I have updated the extradata field with '{}' and it's worked.

Now I have a standart problem: The mobile version of the app is unavailable because it is misconfigured for mobile access. 
As it was earlier, before new version

Now I will try to figure out what is this.  :)

Comment: Is there any solution for this problem diagnostic?